# Add content dynamically to Menu

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx

In my JavaFX application, I am porting my code from pure Java to FXML and have come at one issue.

There are a list of projects in my database. When I goto the `Open Project` Menu, I want to scan through the database and then show put content as `MenuItem` inside the `Menu`. What is the best way of doing it in FXML? Or anyother procedure?

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution is to define an event handler for a Menu's "onShowing" event and add/remove menu items in that event handler. 
http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/Menu.html#setOnShowing(javafx.event.EventHandler)

Answer (score 0):

One way:

- specify the id of the menu in FXML
- declare a Menu variable with the same name as the id in the controller and annotate it with FXML
- use Java code to add dynamic menu items to this menu

Comment: I know that. I want to add it in the fxml itself